# Fuse dead after restart

Tags: java, docker, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, jline

I rebuilt my docker with Fuse (Red Hat Fuse (7.0.0.fuse-000191-redhat-1)
) on Centos 7, and everything is broken now.  I didn't change anything.
Could a yum update cause this?

```
 Exception caught while executing command
org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: 
missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=jline; 
type=karaf.feature; version="[3.6.2,3.6.2]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=jline) 
(type=karaf.feature)(version>=3.6.2)(version<=3.6.2))" [caused by: Unable to 
resolve jline/3.6.2: missing requirement [jline/3.6.2] osgi.identity; 
osgi.identity=org.jline.terminal-jansi; type=osgi.fragment; version=" 
[3.6.2,3.6.2]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Fragment was not selected 
for attachment: org.jline.terminal-jansi/3.6.2]]
```

I've noticed that there's now an extra shell that wasn't there before.

```
admin@root()> features:list | grep shell
shell                                    ? 4.2.3                       ?          ? Uninstalled ? standard-4.2.3                              ? Karaf Shell
shell-compat                             ? 4.2.3                       ?          ? Uninstalled ? standard-4.2.3                              ? Karaf Shell Compatibility
shell                                    ? 4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1  ? x        ? Started     ? standard-4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1         ? Karaf Shell
shell-compat                             ? 4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1  ?          ? Uninstalled ? standard-4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1         ? Karaf Shell Compatibility
```

I know if I upgrade to the latest, I'm going to have to upgrade all my services and fix all the new problems.  Supposed to go live tomorrow.  Why did I have to touch it.

Comment: "I rebuilt my docker with Fuse" - what did you do?
the problem is that you have both Karaf 4.2.3 installed and the Fuse's official 4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1 (from Fuse 7.0.0.GA). Karaf 4.2.3 wasn't even available at the time Fuse 7.0.0.GA was released.

Comment: Yeah pretty weird. The docker contains the RH Fuse folder from 7 months ago. Didn't change a thing. Only update is the yum update in the docker.

Comment: Well I left it for a few hours, and it fixed itself.

Comment: that's very kind from its side ;)

Comment: Btw, I'm getting this error again now, related to the [repo list with LATEST issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56483426/redhat-fuse-updated-features-repo-list).

Comment: just don't use LATEST version. You never know what you'll get.