# Redhat Fuse updated features repo list?

Tags: java, docker, apache-camel, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

I have Red Hat Fuse and AMQ running in a docker. The Fuse and AMQ are baked into the docker from a directory, with shared volumes. They're not being downloaded. The version is v7.0 or v7.1.

I have been away for about 3 weeks and the JVM crashed for some reason.

I rebuilt the docker for good measure and started it up, and our services are failing now.

From what I can tell, the issue is that the feature:repo-list has updated itself. 
( It has broken production, and people are freaking out. )

Is it possible to restore the previous set of feature repos and features, (preferably by altering config files, than manually)

The QA feature list that's been up for 7 weeks has the following:

```
Repository                                  ? URL
???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
fuse-patch-7.0.0.fuse-000191-redhat-1       ? mvn:org.jboss.fuse.modules.patch/patch-features/7.0.0.fuse-000191-redhat-1/xml/features
activemq-core-7.0.0.fuse-000211-redhat-1    ? mvn:org.fusesource/activemq-karaf/7.0.0.fuse-000211-redhat-1/xml/features
org.ops4j.pax.jdbc-1.3.0                    ? mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-features/1.3.0/xml/features
camel-extra-2.21.0.fuse-000054-redhat-1     ? mvn:org.apache-extras.camel-extra.karaf/camel-extra/2.21.0.fuse-000054-redhat-1/xml/features
artemis-2.4.0.amq-711002-redhat-1           ? mvn:org.apache.activemq/artemis-features/2.4.0.amq-711002-redhat-1/xml/features
org.ops4j.pax.web-7.0.0                     ? mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-features/7.0.0/xml/features
framework-4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1        ? mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/framework/4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1/xml/features
standard-4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1         ? mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/standard/4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1/xml/features
karaf-features-core-droolsjbpm-7.11.0.Final ? mvn:org.kie/kie-karaf-features/7.11.0.Final/xml/features-core
fuse-framework-7.0.0.fuse-000191-redhat-1   ? mvn:org.jboss.fuse/fuse-karaf-framework/7.0.0.fuse-000191-redhat-1/xml/features
pax-jms-1.0.0                               ? mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jms/pax-jms-features/1.0.0/xml/features
camel-2.21.0-000033.fuse-000001             ? mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/RELEASE/xml/features
hibernate-osgi                              ? mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-osgi/5.1.10.Final-redhat-1/xml/karaf
enterprise-4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1       ? mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/enterprise/4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1/xml/features
jclouds-2.0.3                               ? mvn:org.apache.jclouds.karaf/jclouds-karaf/2.0.3/xml/features
spring-legacy-4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1    ? mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/spring-legacy/4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1/xml/features
cxf-3.1.11.fuse-000243-redhat-1             ? mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.1.11.fuse-000243-redhat-1/xml/features
cxf-3.1.11-000176.fuse-000001               ? mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.1.11-000176.fuse-000001/xml/features
camel-2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1           ? mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1/xml/features
pax-transx-0.3.0                            ? mvn:org.ops4j.pax.transx/pax-transx-features/0.3.0/xml/features
org.ops4j.pax.cdi-1.0.0                     ? mvn:org.ops4j.pax.cdi/pax-cdi-features/1.0.0/xml/features
hawtio-2.0.0.fuse-000172-redhat-1           ? mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/2.0.0.fuse-000172-redhat-1/xml/features
jclouds-2.1.0                               ? mvn:org.apache.jclouds.karaf/jclouds-karaf/2.1.0/xml/features
hibernate-validator-osgi-features           ? mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features/5.3.5.Final-redhat-2/xml/features
karaf-features-droolsjbpm-7.11.0.Final      ? mvn:org.kie/kie-karaf-features/7.11.0.Final/xml/features
aries-jpa-2.6.1                             ? mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/jpa-features/2.6.1/xml/features
```

The new list is:

```
fuse-patch-7.0.0.fuse-000191-redhat-1       ? mvn:org.jboss.fuse.modules.patch/patch-features/7.0.0.fuse-000191-redhat-1/xml/features
activemq-core-7.0.0.fuse-000211-redhat-1    ? mvn:org.fusesource/activemq-karaf/7.0.0.fuse-000211-redhat-1/xml/features
org.ops4j.pax.jdbc-1.3.0                    ? mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-features/1.3.0/xml/features
camel-extra-2.21.0.fuse-000054-redhat-1     ? mvn:org.apache-extras.camel-extra.karaf/camel-extra/2.21.0.fuse-000054-redhat-1/xml/features
artemis-2.4.0.amq-711002-redhat-1           ? mvn:org.apache.activemq/artemis-features/2.4.0.amq-711002-redhat-1/xml/features
hibernate-validator-osgi-features           ? mvn:org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features/6.0.14.Final/xml/features
org.ops4j.pax.web-7.0.0                     ? mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-features/7.0.0/xml/features
framework-4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1        ? mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/framework/4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1/xml/features
standard-4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1         ? mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/standard/4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1/xml/features
karaf-features-core-droolsjbpm-7.11.0.Final ? mvn:org.kie/kie-karaf-features/7.11.0.Final/xml/features-core
fuse-framework-7.0.0.fuse-000191-redhat-1   ? mvn:org.jboss.fuse/fuse-karaf-framework/7.0.0.fuse-000191-redhat-1/xml/features
pax-jms-1.0.0                               ? mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jms/pax-jms-features/1.0.0/xml/features
camel-2.23.2.fuse-740002                    ? mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/RELEASE/xml/features
hibernate-osgi                              ? mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-osgi/5.1.10.Final-redhat-1/xml/karaf
enterprise-4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1       ? mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/enterprise/4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1/xml/features
org.ops4j.pax.cdi-1.1.2                     ? mvn:org.ops4j.pax.cdi/pax-cdi-features/1.1.2/xml/features
cxf-3.2.7.fuse-sb2-740008                   ? mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.2.7.fuse-sb2-740008/xml/features
spring-legacy-4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1    ? mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/spring-legacy/4.2.0.fuse-000237-redhat-1/xml/features
cxf-3.1.11.fuse-000243-redhat-1             ? mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.1.11.fuse-000243-redhat-1/xml/features
hapi-fhir-3.5.0                             ? mvn:ca.uhn.hapi.fhir.karaf/hapi-fhir/3.5.0/xml/features
camel-2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1           ? mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/2.21.0.fuse-000077-redhat-1/xml/features
pax-transx-0.3.0                            ? mvn:org.ops4j.pax.transx/pax-transx-features/0.3.0/xml/features
org.ops4j.pax.cdi-1.0.0                     ? mvn:org.ops4j.pax.cdi/pax-cdi-features/1.0.0/xml/features
hawtio-2.0.0.fuse-000172-redhat-1           ? mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/2.0.0.fuse-000172-redhat-1/xml/features
jclouds-2.1.1                               ? mvn:org.apache.jclouds.karaf/jclouds-karaf/2.1.1/xml/features
jclouds-2.1.0                               ? mvn:org.apache.jclouds.karaf/jclouds-karaf/2.1.0/xml/features
hibernate-validator-osgi-features           ? mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-validator-osgi-karaf-features/5.3.5.Final-redhat-2/xml/features
karaf-features-droolsjbpm-7.11.0.Final      ? mvn:org.kie/kie-karaf-features/7.11.0.Final/xml/features
aries-jpa-2.6.1                             ? mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/jpa-features/2.6.1/xml/features
```

The org.apache.karaf.features.repos.cfg has:

```
> enterprise=mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/enterprise/${karaf.version}/xml/features
> enterprise-legacy=mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/enterprise-legacy/${karaf.version}/xml/features
> spring=mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/spring/${karaf.version}/xml/features
> spring-legacy=mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/spring-legacy/${karaf.version}/xml/features
> cellar=mvn:org.apache.karaf.cellar/apache-karaf-cellar/RELEASE/xml/features
> cave=mvn:org.apache.karaf.cave/apache-karaf-cave/RELEASE/xml/features
> camel=mvn:org.apache.camel.karaf/apache-camel/RELEASE/xml/features
> camel-extras=mvn:org.apache-extras.camel-extra.karaf/camel-extra/RELEASE/xml/features
> cxf=mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/RELEASE/xml/features
> cxf-dosgi=mvn:org.apache.cxf.dosgi/cxf-dosgi/RELEASE/xml/features
> cxf-dosgi-samples=mvn:org.apache.cxf.dosgi/cxf-dosgi-samples/RELEASE/xml/features
> cxf-xkms=mvn:org.apache.cxf.services.xkms/cxf-services-xkms-features/RELEASE/xml
> jclouds=mvn:org.apache.jclouds.karaf/jclouds-karaf/RELEASE/xml/features
> hawtio=mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/RELEASE/xml/features
> pax-cdi=mvn:org.ops4j.pax.cdi/pax-cdi-features/RELEASE/xml/features
> pax-jdbc=mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jdbc/pax-jdbc-features/RELEASE/xml/features
> pax-jms=mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jms/pax-jms-features/RELEASE/xml/features
> pax-jpa=mvn:org.ops4j.pax.jpa/pax-jpa-features/RELEASE/xml/features
> pax-transx=mvn:org.ops4j.pax.transx/pax-transx-features/RELEASE/xml/features
> pax-keycloak=mvn:org.ops4j.pax.keycloak/pax-keycloak-features/RELEASE/xml/features pax-web=mvn:org.ops4j.pax.web/pax-web-features/RELEASE/xml/features
> decanter=mvn:org.apache.karaf.decanter/apache-karaf-decanter/RELEASE/xml/features
> aries-jpa=mvn:org.apache.aries.jpa/jpa-features/RELEASE/xml/features
> aries-rsa=mvn:org.apache.aries.rsa/rsa-features/RELEASE/xml/features
> hibernate=mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-osgi/RELEASE/xml/karaf
> ignite=mvn:org.apache.ignite/ignite-osgi-karaf/RELEASE/xml/features
> artemis=mvn:org.apache.activemq/artemis-features/RELEASE/xml/features
```

Comment: SO is not good place for urgent issues with your production. Red Hat support is available 24x7 and S1 issues are resolved within one hour. (If you have followed Fuse End User Licence and purchased subscription for production use.)

Comment: Red Hat Fuse is Apache licensed. I don't have $23,760/year to get a production license.  If someone answers my question, great.  If not, I'll figure something out.

Comment: Even in the first place you had both `cxf-3.1.11.fuse-000243-redhat-1` and `cxf-3.1.11-000176.fuse-000001`. Now you additionally have `cxf-3.2.7.fuse-sb2-740008`. You said that _The Fuse and AMQ are baked into the docker from a directory_ - I guess you used `RELEASE` or `LATEST` somewhere which means the set of features (not feature repositories) is not fixed. I.e., you don't use concrete versions, but either ranges or RELEASE/LATEST maven special keywords. This means the Maven infra inside Fuse is doing what's it told to do - tries to use different version.

Comment: Yes you are violating the Red Hat terms

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz, yeah that makes sense, I'll try use concrete versions. Claus, can you send a link to the supposed violation? Red Hat's site clearly lists Fuse under Apache license.

Comment: feature:repo-remove doesn't remove repos from the list.  Is that a bug?